# Is it possible to inject scripts file dynamically into html using Node.js?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm trying to get the `*.js` from specific path and inject the scripts into `index.html` file.

I've used below `node.js` code to retrieve the files from the directory.

```
function walkSync(currentDirPath, callback) {
    var fs = require('fs'),
        path = require('path');
    fs.readdirSync(currentDirPath).forEach(function (name) {
        var filePath = path.join(currentDirPath, name);
        var stat = fs.statSync(filePath);
        if (stat.isFile()) {
            callback(filePath, stat);
        } else if (stat.isDirectory()) {
            walkSync(filePath, callback);
        }
    });
}

var componentsFilePath = [];
walkSync("app/scripts/", function (filePath, stats) {
    if (filePath.indexOf(".js") > 0) {
        componentsFilePath.push(filePath);
    }
});

console.log("scripts : " + componentsFilePath);
```

Now, I'm facing challenge to inject.

Is't possible to inject the above scripts files to the `html` page.

Appreciate your support.

Comment: You'd simply use a HTML parser of sorts to edit the file directly, if I am understanding your question. The process would be parse the HTML -> Place them in the corret location in the contents -> save the file. NPM should have multiple modules which will make this trivial.

Comment: I'm not finding good reference. Can you share it you got one please.

Comment: normally you want to do it with some build tool such as [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) or [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/). Here is gulp package: [gulp-inject](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject). Or I misunderstood your case, what do you mean by dynamically?

Comment: @AlexanderSuvorov, I'm using build tool for normal inject(static js files). This is the case, where I should get the *.js files dynamically with given directory path, for that I've written node code. So, similarly I'm looking for the node program to inject the scripts into the html page.